# Heroku command: read $Recycle.Bin: Handle is invalid

Tags: heroku, command-line-interface, heroku-toolbelt

On any heroku command, like `heroku`, `heroky open` or `heroku ps`, my system (windows) keeps saying:

```
read C:\$Recycle.Bin: The handle is invalid.
```

multiple times, followed by

```
EISDIR: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
```

I have no clue what's going wrong. Is this an ssh problem? Looks like it is looking for a file in my recycle bin, which is empty.
Commands like `heroku _` or `heroku login` work, though they also give the `handle is invalid` error multiple times.
I already reinstalled heroku with git. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appeared to be an invironment variable `SSL_CERT_DIR` which I had set to `C:\` trying to fix some other (windows) problems.

After some searching, I found removing the recycle bin with this command:

```
rd /s /q C:\$Recycle.bin
```

resulted in the same error, but with `$recycle.bin` replaced by the first folder appearing in `C:/`. That gave me a hint to search for anything pointing to `C:/`.

Hope this helps anyone getting the same error to spend less time on it :)